# validate set of fields including pickList

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces, picklist

I have a form with radio button, inputText and picklist.
assuming each component is validated, I need to validate the combination of this 3 components and then show a validation message.
Also, I have for each component a dedicated  tag and another general message(fixed text) at the top of the page that is shown if there is a validation failed message.

My requirement is to show(in addition to the general message) a message that the combination of this 3 components is invalid.

here is some pseudo code:

```
<p:outputPanel id="generalErrorMessage" rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}">
    some general error message
</p:outputPanel>

// HERE I NEED TO ADD MY 3 COMPONENTS COMBINATION VALIDATION ERROR

<p:inputText id="inputTxt">
    <f:validator binding="#{someTxtValidator}"/>
</p:inputText>
<p:message for="inputTxt"/>

<p:selectOneRadio id="myadio">    ....  </p:selectOneRadio>

<p:pickList> .... </p:pickList>

<p:commandButton value="SAVE" action="#{saveMethod}"/>
```

I'm using jsf 2 and primefaces 3.4.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a case for [o:validateAll](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateAll)?

Comment: My requirement changed so I don't need to deal with it right now. Thank's mabi